# Regex to capture also outer parts of html fragment

Tags: regex, tags, pcre

The issue is shown online https://regex101.com/r/wZ9oX5/4

The subject string is a html fragment with some **code** tags. I would need a regex pattern to get parts of that string that are between text of code htaml elements. This parts should contain code opening and closing tag too.

Example subject pattern:

```
abc
<code fsa='fdsa'>
    lorem
</code>
bcd
<code fsa='fdsa'>
    ipsum
</code>
cde
<code fsa='fdsa'>
    quo vadis
</code>
desf
```

My pattern is this:

```
(<\/code>.*?<code[^>]*?>)
```

But it only gets the inner parts of the string. Is it possible to create a pattern that would get outer parts of the string too?

I mean aditional parts such as

```
abc
<code fsa='fdsa'>
```

and

```
</code>
defs
```

Thank you

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to use regex to parse HTML? You can safe yourself a load of pain by just using DOM http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php

Comment: Why don't you try the other way around - [check this](https://regex101.com/r/wZ9oX5/5). It replaces everything in the `code` block with nothing - including tags.

Comment: Yes, there is a reason. This is because text nodes of code tags can have "less than" characters that makes DOMDocument crazy. It is not a real html fragment then, I know, but this is the way to store articles with programming code snippets in the database.

Comment: @ClasG The pattern should get parts **between** code texts. It is between 'lorem', 'ipsum' and 'quo vadis'

Comment: @trzczy I'm pretty sure you would like to convert `>` to `&gt;` and `<` to `&lt;` for literal text, assuming you are storing HTML.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't follow you... Do you want `lorem ipsum quo vadis` or `abc bcd cde desf`? Because my example **keeps** the `abc...` - check the substituition at the bottom of regex101, and that's how I interpret what you want from your question.

Comment: @andlrc yes, I just create alternative way. Converting before store to DB also need regex operations. And I need one-char chars to count them. My system will count the number of chars in article.

Comment: @ClasG No, we should consider MATCH INFORMATION at the bottom right. This is that what is in parenthesis in the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: https://regex101.com/r/wZ9oX5/6

```
((^|<\/code>).*?(<code[^>]*?>|$))/gs
```